# NoMethodError in RUBY ON RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi all I am new in Ruby on Rails and have this problem

when I go to

> localhost/proyects

This error is triggered

```
NoMethodError in Proyects#index 

Showing /home/mariano/pepcode/starter_project/app/views/proyects/index.html.erb where       line #5 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #5):

2:   <p>Projects</p>
3: </header>
4: 
5: <%= render @projects %>
6: 
7: <br />
This is
```

This is the content of index.html.erb

```
<header>
 <p>Projects</p>
</header>
<%= render @projects %>
<br />

and this is the content of the partial  _project.html.erb  which the  index view  points

 <div class="project">
   <h1> <%= project.title %></h1>    
 </div>
```

This is the code of Proyect Controller

```
class ProyectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @proyects = Proyect.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.xml  { render :xml => @proyects }
   end
  end
 end
```

Comment: We need a lot more information here. What is the full error? Where is this method being called?

Comment: Post your full error stack

Comment: Post your controller code.

Comment: Is your controller called `ProyectsController`? If then should be `ProjectsController`.

Comment: the j or y  here is the error

Comment: Yep, you can change `render @projects` to `render @proyects`, but i think you should use proper language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just rename this line `<%= render @projects %>` to `<%= render @proyects %>` to fix the error,but giving a meaningful name is always useful and encouraged.

You should be renaming your controller code to like this

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @projects = Project.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.xml  { render :xml => @proyects }
   end
  end
 end
```

And also the controller file name to **`projects_controller.rb`** and your **`views folder`** to **`projects`** And probably your model name to **`Project`**.

Comment: Thank you- already solve this error. Thank you very much to you

Comment: @user3554170 Glad to help and please accept my answer by making the tick-mark green :)